# How to merge band and column?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I am newbie in devexpress and WPF, but I need to make grid with bands. I will illustrate 2 pict: 1st - what I've done, 2nd - what I have to do, but don't know how. Pay attention to first column
[image]
[image]

Here is the code of the first pict grid:

```
<Window xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"  x:Class="DbExpressTest.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DbExpressTest"
    xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainView" Height="350" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True">
        <dxg:GridControl.Bands>
            <dxg:GridControlBand>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="New Column"></dxg:GridColumn>
            </dxg:GridControlBand>

            <dxg:GridControlBand Header="Cars" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center">
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name" Header="Name"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Year" Header="Year"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Type" Header="Type"/>
            </dxg:GridControlBand>
            <dxg:GridControlBand>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Owner" Header="Owner"></dxg:GridColumn>
            </dxg:GridControlBand>
        </dxg:GridControl.Bands>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" ShowTotalSummary="True"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution..... Just add "ShowColumnHeaders" into table view with "False" value!

```
...
<dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" ShowTotalSummary="True" ShowColumnHeaders="False"/>
</dxg:GridControl.View>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer at this address: [How to Merge Band-Header with Column-Header](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T232806)

[image]